# PhantomJs - How to render a multi page PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I can create one-page PDFs with phantomJS; but I can't find on the doc how to create different pages (each page coming from an html view) and put them into one PDF ? I am using node-phantom module for NodeJS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just need to specify a `paperSize`.

Like this with module **"phantom": "0.5.1"**

```
function(next) {
    phantom.create(function(doc) {
        next(null, doc);
    }, "phantomjs", Math.floor(Math.random()*(65535-49152+1)+49152));
},
function(ph, next) {
    ph.createPage(function(doc) {
        next(null, doc);
    });
},
function(page, next) {
    page.set('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});
    page.set('zoomFactor', 1);
}
```

Then, simply use **page-break-before: always;** in your HTML content each time you want to open a new page.

PS: I use async.waterfall in this example

PPS: Math.random on port number is used to avoid module crash if concurrent calls to phantom binary are triggered. Works fine - if someone wants to post something better even if a bit off-topic, feel free to do it

Comment: do you know how to create one pdf from multiple htmls ? thank you

Comment: Well, concatenate the bodies of the htmls and go for it