# PDF Generation in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I have requirement where i need to create  a PDF from html in node  .In addition to that i must be able to add custom header and footer.  Then content of the web page should be in multiple pages based on custom requirement. that is we must able to decide what content should be which page.
After searching i found some solutions like phantom , but there is no proper documentation which could help me. 
I need some way to do this.
Found a solution 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027142/phantomjs-how-to-render-a-multi-page-pdf?rq=1) , but explanation is not good enough.

Comment: please specify what you have tried so far , please post the code that you have tried and the error you have got. then only people can find you a solutions

Comment: Tried pdfkit . but it doesn't seems to accept a  html input.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple module with [webshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot)

Step I follow:-

- Create HTML using the node-phantom-simple
- After creating the HTML use that HTML to pass it in webshot.

```js
var driver = require('node-phantom-simple');
var webshot = require('webshot');



driver.create({path: require('phantomjs').path, 'parameters': {'disk-cache': 'yes'}}, function (err, browser) {
        return browser.createPage(function (err, page) {
            return page.open(url, function (err, status) {
                console.log("opened site? ", status,page.content);
                 return page.evaluate(File.cleanHtml, function (err, html) {

                      var options = {
                        streamType: 'pdf',
                        screenSize: {
                            width: 1200,
                            height: 300
                        },
                        shotSize: {
                            width: 1200,
                            height: 300
                        },
                        siteType:'html',// include this to generate PDF from html
                        phantomConfig: {'ssl-protocol':'any','ignore-ssl-errors': 'true'}
                      } 

                      var pdfname = 'test_' + Date.now() + '.pdf';

                      webshot(html,pdfname,options, function(err) {
                        console.log("err in webshot",err);  
                      })
                    });
                // });
            });
        });
    });
```

Here File.cleanHtml is a function I have created which is used to remove extra content from HTML.you can directly return same HTML from this function.may be something like this :)

```js
    cleanHtml: function () {
        var data = $("html");
        return "<html>" + data.html() + "</html>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  i will try this solution.

Comment: I didn't understand where we feed the html content into the code and how do we separate html contents in each page based on our condition?

Comment: Also i must be able to decide what content should be which page, if there is a paragraph and i want a page break after that paragraph . i should be able to do that.

Comment: i tried this. it doesn't work properly. t doesn't include css styles.